# Kubuntu 22.04 desktop freeze problem

Tags: kubuntu, vlc

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 and in some cases, my desktop and mouse freeze randomly for a few moments and then it gets resolved after two or three seconds, but these incidents and the frequency of these freezes are increasing over time, to the point where I have to restart the system. I realized that this problem does not occur for me in normal mode, and when I run the vlc program, this problem starts and the issue is not resolved by closing vlc. Have you experienced this?

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-45-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-12500H
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
```

And graphics card specifications:

```
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU
NVIDIA Driver Version: 525.116.04
NVML Version:12.525.116.04
```